# Compare bas64 data from png image node.js

Tags: node.js

I want to compare the base64 image from png file, so i am using jimp to decode base64 and write to disk but it writes half of the image; is it possible to compare base64 image to png file directly??

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: basically i have two images one is in base64 format and another images is in png so i want to match both images.